# Angular 8: Access 2 identical components placed on app-root

Tags: angular, components

**app.component.html**

```
<app-son></app-son>
<app-son></app-son>
```

I placed 2 identical components in app.component.html
Upon ngOnInit, each component should take its data from a global service I wrote.

How can a component know, if it is the upper one or the lower one?

Is there a way to "inject" data so that each will have an ID?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please elaborate. Maybe also throw in some code to help us understand better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **@ViewChildren** for grouping children components into array:

```
@Component(...)
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit { 

  @ViewChildren(SonComponent)
  sons: QueryList<SonComponent>

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const sonsArr = this.sons.toArray()
    console.log(sonsArray) // logs array of Son components    
  }

}
```

So first element of the logged array - **sonsArr[0]** is above the second - **sonsArr[1]**

Here is StackBlitz link for demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvsio5

***Note: open console***

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code. I ran: console.log(sons)  and got undefined. Can you please help ?

Comment: I have edited the answer, the wrong hook was used, ngOnInit would console log successfully only if children weren't components but simple elements like div, p etc. So the ngAfterViewInit should be used here.

Comment: I modified the code. In ngAfterViewInit, when I tried to change a value in a 'son' object, I got: ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: undefined'. Current value: 'null: MyNewVal'

Comment: That is a common behaviour when you try to change variable (that is used in template) in an angular hook (like ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit, .etc). What you can do, you can wrap your code(where you do your modifications on son object) with setTimeout function. E.g. setTimeout(() => { /* code goes here */ }, 0). What this is doing is putting your function in the event loop that will wait for other functions to complete, in your case hook ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:
In the parent HTML:

```
<app-son [id]="0"></app-son>
<app-son [id]="1"></app-son>
```

In the child ts:

```
@Input() id: number;

ngOnInit() {
console.log (this.id);
```

}

This way, each child knows its id.